# How can I view the source code of a used php file hide my source code at tool.eddiekidiw.com

Tags: php

I need to edit a piece of code in this file, but I cannot read its source code. Does anyone have a way to read it? I just know it's encrypted at tool.eddiekidiw.com

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The file is obfuscated or encoded not sure what library is used by this tool.
I hate to say it but it could take a lot of time to find how to decode it, the best way to cope with this is to look for the original file.

Because you didn't post the code here it is harder to help, to get more help you will probably need to post the entire code.

I did see in your image that the code is being executed by the php-phar extension, this led me to believe that the code is just compressed, I cannot confirm this.

Comment: I can't find the author of this source code, this is an encoded file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCrGDuFBmQdy-PEQ3QK_BEAevzu3ZHbi/view?usp=sharing